# How to calculate Age between two date in sql

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to calculate the value of "Age" field depending on the Birthday "DOB" field
Depending on the default value for the field "Age"

Comment: And what have you done so far? You need to tell us what have you tried till now, and what error or problem you are facing with

Answer (score 0):

its easy, you need to use built-in function: `DATEDIFF(YEAR,DOB,getdate())`

Comment: Thanks for your help
But it does not work, maybe I did not know what you mean I am a beginner in Sql Server 

But I know it's in Oracle are: (sysdat-hiredate)/365

see this snapshot of error :
https://www.dropbox.com/s/meg6xhdertv3fvd/12333.PNG?dl=0